# How to specify sender email address in Mailgun not the Gmail but some company domain email which is repayable

Tags: laravel, email, sendmail, mailgun

I have gone through the documentation and Q&A, I have been searching for this for this quite long, please help me through this and let me know if I am forgetting or missing something important.

I am sending an email using mailgun to the user when they Signup on my website and I am using laravel.

> 1: When I specify the sender address like  `someone@gmail.com` (It 
>        works)
>
> 2: When I specify the sender's address like `someone@mycompany.com` (It Failed) and I have no idea why??

I have gone through the basic documentation of setup and sending email, and I get to know you can specify the receiver address, and I don't know from where to set up the sender address

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('Someone@company.com', 'Company')
    ->subject('Sign Up')
    ->cc('others@company.com')
    ->view('emails.automated_signup_email');
}
```

This is the build function of mailable class if you want more info mailable class you can see this  link https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail

Comment: In Mailgun you need to add your domain and  verify it. Once verified, you can specify in mailgun your sender email @yourdomain.tld . Then copy those credentials in Laravel

Comment: @codiiv by the time I was looking into the same problem someone faced but there is no answer so can where I can specify sender? and can i specify domain like company.com and the sender email to sender@company.com

Comment: Yes you can.
1) Login to Mailgun and  add your domain there. They will require you to verify domain ownership by sending you some DNS record to verify at the domain registrar's level
2) Once added, and verified you can verify the sending details in .env  file of your Laravel application

Comment: @codiiv in sandbox environment can I specify this sender??? here is the thing my sandbox is set up can I make it ?? or i have to setup a custom domain for this?

Comment: In Mailgun you can create multiple "senders"  https://screenshots.firefox.com/iS2yqUUGQzwnKCnn/app.mailgun.com

Comment: @codiiv thank you very much, i have almost reach at the end of the problem